# How JSON should be like when dealing with ember-data

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

i would like to know how the properties of a JSON should be liked when dealing with the ember-data library.

I was searching about it and i found that should be like this:

I want get all my BOOKINGS, for example, so should be like this:

```
{
  "data": [
   {
    "id": "209039090239390",
    "type": "booking",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Booking one"
    }
   },
   {
    "id": "209039090239390",
    "type": "booking",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Booking two"
    }
   }
  ]
}
```

So, in this case, i have two bookings, and each one have the name attribute. Perfect until now? Let's continue.

Now, in my Ember Model, **HOW** should i define this?? **(That's what i want know)**

Like this:

```
App.BookingModel = DS.Model.extend({
 type: DS.attr('string'),
 attributes: {
   name: DS.attr('string')
 }
});
```

Or like this:

```
App.BookingModel = DS.Model.extend({
 type: DS.attr('string'),
 name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I'm using the first option, but i can't access the attributes object, because will throw an error:

```
Error while processing route: bookings Cannot read property '_attributes' of undefined
```

I already try to define as the second option, but than the result will be undefined, cause in my JSON, the NAME is inside attribute. I could change it and take off the attribute, but i want follow the convention..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your model, the only thing you need is this:

```
App.BookingModel = DS.Model.extend({
 name: DS.attr('string)
});
```

Ember data uses the JSON convention to create the model. It looks at the type parameter in the JSON to connect to the ember model, and looks at the attributes to connect to the ember model's attributes.

Comment: but it cant find the name if he is inside the attributes @TylerIguchi

Comment: should i take of? but this is not the json convention?

Comment: If you're using the `JSONAPIAdapter` in your application, it knows how to traverse JSON in the "JSONAPI" format automatically. You just need to list the attributes in your model. See the docs: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html (Tyler's answer is the correct one)

Comment: I'm not understand what i should do. So i define the model like the Tyler did, but the JSON, need have the attributes or not? Please, give me a full answer, i'm new with ember, i'm not understand what i should do :/

Comment: if i define like this, and send the json with the attributes, i can't grab the properties, using attributes.name or just name.. why ember is so difficult? the documentation is very poor..

Comment: i'm seeing that no one really knows ember.. =/

Comment: The JSON you provided in your question adheres to the JSON API spec (http://jsonapi.org/) Ember data's JSONAPIAdapter (the default adapter in 2.0 AFAIK) knows the attributes of a record are in the 'attributes' hash, and so you would access it like `this.get("name")`. You could use another adapter like the REST adapter (or write your own to use whatever JSON you want), but JSON API is probably the best solution, ideally paired with a compliant serialiser on the server side (e.g. ActiveModelSerializers for Rails)

Comment: @someName Read Ashley's comment in full. Leave your JSON as is. Define the model as per Tyler's answer. If you want to access fields (where?) then ask another question - accessing specific fields in a template is another step. The Ember docs cover this pretty well.